# Insert margins (addmargins()) between rows in a table (table()) in R

Tags: r, insert, margins, contingency

I am trying to create 2x2 contingency tables that contain both the calculations of the intersections (i.e., observations), their margins, as well as their totals, but with mixed results.

I got to this point†:

```
test <- matrix(c(220,24,180,27), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
propTable <- prop.table(test)
test <- matrix(c(220,24,propTable[1, 1:2],180,27,propTable[2, 1:2]), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(test) <- c("No","Yes")
rownames(test) <- c("Male","%","Female","%")

print(test, digits = 3)
```

Which gives the following result

```
            No     Yes
Male   220.000 24.0000
%        0.488  0.0532
Female 180.000 27.0000
%        0.399  0.0599
```

However, when I try to add margins, the operation in columns obviously fails (rows seem ok) as it factors in the percentages:

```
print(addmargins(test), digits = 3)
```

Result:

```
            No     Yes     Sum
Male   220.000 24.0000 244.000
%        0.488  0.0532   0.541
Female 180.000 27.0000 207.000
%        0.399  0.0599   0.459
Sum    400.887 51.1131 452.000
```

My questions:

1. Is there a simpler way (command, function?) to realise the first part (both with base commands and with packages)?
2. If there is, what is the way to obtain the correct margins, if yes, how?
3. Is there a way to have decimals for the percentages, but round numbers for the observations, if yes, how?
4. If there is no easier/simpler way for question 1, what do I have to do in order to obtain the correct margins with my code?

---

† Code inspired from [cylismo.org](https://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/tables.html#creating-a-table-directly)

---

`sessioninfo::session_info()` and `installed.packages()[(.packages()),c(3,5)]` extracts:

```
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
 os       macOS Monterey 12.6
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0
 rstudio  2022.07.1+554 Spotted Wakerobin (desktop)
-------------------------------------------------------
          Version Depends
stats     "4.2.1" NA
graphics  "4.2.1" NA
grDevices "4.2.1" NA
utils     "4.2.1" NA
datasets  "4.2.1" NA
methods   "4.2.1" NA
base      "4.2.1" NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m1 <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(test), nrow = nrow(test),
   dimnames = dimnames(test))
m1[setdiff(row.names(test), "%"), colnames(test)] <- test[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
m2 <- addmargins(m1)
m2[c(FALSE, TRUE), colnames(test)] <- test[c(FALSE, TRUE), ]
```

-output

```
> m2
                No         Yes Sum
Male   220.0000000 24.00000000 244
%        0.4878049  0.05321508   0
Female 180.0000000 27.00000000 207
%        0.3991131  0.05986696   0
Sum    400.0000000 51.00000000 451
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Akrun. I suppose it is related to my 1st question, isn't it? Nevertheless, I added your line just after ```test <- matrix(c(220,24,180,27), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)```, but I got the following error message: ```Error in colSums(test[c(TRUE, FALSE), ]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions```